# ios : edits to local resource files dont get copied to the device

Tags: html, ios, xcode, resources

I have a bunch of local HTML files that get loaded in UIWebView. If I edit them in Xcode, they dont get reflected when I run the app in emulator or device. Doesnt work even if I CLEAN first.

What does work is deleting the app manually from the device / emulator before a CLEAN + BUILD + RUN. This is a time taking process.

Wondering if I can fiddle with some build setting in xcode so that, similar to source and xib files, HTML and other resource files also get copied to the app bundle upon editing them.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me, I usually need to do a "Deep Clean"  (a clean with the option key pressed.)  If that fails, I delete the derived data folder contents (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/).

I don't know why Xcode does this.